# JSON images url instead of base64

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, base64

I'm using Three.js to save and load objects in a database. I'm inserting my objects as JSON.

The problem is that JSON.stringify or toJSON() transform the image url (textures) in base64, and I wanted to keep the http url.

This is the originial JSON:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        [...]
    },
    "geometries": [
        {
            [...]
        }],
    "materials": [
        {
            [...]
        }],
    "textures": [
        {
            [...]
        }],
    "images": [
        {
            "uuid": "4ED9CE3E-7C8A-4EB7-8CF8-D90B3527DF5F",
            "url": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoATyuRZGZVREd0FAERRRBAEBEFwAYEyKqP/Rfozx+5fDYjvpeT/akv+n/J+/7eMjX9Ke8uojP4JVAYAyuj/Ld3Por7fPQ9i8d7vvr8LKNzLg/dn1u1hvQf3q/v92vRX0X/ [...]"
        }],
    "object": {
        [...]
    }
}
```

And the desired kind of JSON would be this :

```
{
    "metadata": {
        [...]
    },
    "geometries": [
        {
            [...]
        }],
    "materials": [
        {
            [...]
        }],
    "textures": [
        {
            [...]
        }],
    "images": [
        {
            "uuid": "4ED9CE3E-7C8A-4EB7-8CF8-D90B3527DF5F",
            "url": "http://www.domain.com/picture/path.png"
        }],
    "object": {
        [...]
    }
}
```

Is there a solution to do this ?

Comment: How do you use `stringify` function?

Comment: `var objectJson = SELECTED.toJSON();
   objectJson = JSON.stringify( objectJson, null, '\t' );
   objectJson = objectJson.replace( /[\n\t]+([\d\.e\-\[\]]+)/g, '$1' );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying the JSON file and getting my texture path, I did the following:

```
var objectParsed = SELECTED.toJSON(); //transform the selected object in JSON
textureBase64 = objectParsed.images[0].url; //get the value of the base64 encoded image
objectParsed.images[0].url = texMap; // replace the base64 encoded image with the http texture path

objectParsed = JSON.stringify( objectParsed, null, '\t' );
objectParsed = objectParsed.replace( /[\n\t]+([\d\.e\-\[\]]+)/g, '$1' ); // make the JSON readable
```

And now it did the trick ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem and solved it by overwriting `Source.toJSON()` as follows:

```
Source.prototype.toJSON = function ( meta ) {

    const isRootObject = ( meta === undefined || typeof meta === 'string' );

    if ( !isRootObject && meta.images[ this.uuid ] !== undefined ) {
        return meta.images[ this.uuid ];
    }

    const output = {
        uuid: this.uuid,
        url: this.data.src
    };

    if ( !isRootObject ) {
        meta.images[ this.uuid ] = output;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Alternatively, you can store the relative URL of the image by using `this.data.getAttribute('src')`.